# is it safe to Install Ubuntu 14.04 packages on Kubuntu 14.04?

Tags: package-management, kubuntu

I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS installed on my computer and a friend of mine has Kubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr installed on his machine, which has no connection to the internet.

I want to share with him some packages I've installed on my Ubuntu (such as texlive-full, for example), basically I'll copy and paste `/var/cache/apt/packages` to his machine (I have a really slow connection to the internet).

It that possible ?
Could anything go wrong ?

Comment: Is that 10.04 a typo? And have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Comment: You can not share packages between versions. See the link I gave you for installing without an internet.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, although, as bodhi.zazen pointed out, you should be careful if it's between different versions of Ubuntu. Also, simply copying `/var/cache/apt/archives` won't install the packages-you need to install them all still.

Comment: @hal7df Are Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and Kubuntu 14.04 LTS compatible?

Comment: @Rhonda Yes, they should be -- the .1 just means that it's past a certain milestone in its support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference between Ubuntu and Kubuntu is the desktop interface you're using. The underlying system is still the same.

So, as long as the computers are running the same version, it will work. (The third number on LTS releases just indicates an update milestone -- not an entirely different version)

I should warn you, though, that installing packages this way does not guarantee that all of the dependencies of your packages will be installed. Be careful if you do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

In synaptic you can select the packages you want to install and under the first menu there is an option to generate a script which you can take to another machine and run there.

This script will download with wget all the packages you specified that you wanted and their dependencies.

Once run you'll have all the package files needed.

Carry them on a CD/USB stick and install them by:

```
sudo su
dpkg -i *.deb
```